# icon of the .desktop file does not show in unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I created the launcher for the Ranger filemanager like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon[pl_PL]=/
Name[pl_PL]=Ranger
Exec=/usr/bin/ranger
Name=Ranger
Icon=/home/yemu/.icons/Ranger.png
```

Unfortunately, the icon only shows on the .desktop file, but after I run it, in the launches there's default grey icon with gear instead of the ine defined in the file.

Comment: Have you tried a reset of unity? or just a rebooting of your system?

Comment: Try to remove the [pl_PL] entries. They are doing nothing. Also where have you saved the .desktop file?

Comment: I have .desktop file saved in /usr/share/applications, the app shows up when I search for it in unity. but shows without the icon, in the launcher it has the grey gear icon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm self posting the answer I found on the internet, here's my desktop entry, temporarily using baobab icon, but I hope I'll manage to change that. ranger shows up as an indepentent app, and I can swith to it with Super+Number, and that's mainly the thing I wanted to achieve. Using this method I also managed to add some bookmarks to the left-click menu of this launcher.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ranger Filemanager
Comment=File management utility
Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable --class=myserver -x ranger
StartupWMClass=myserver
Icon=baobab
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Dir1;Dir2;

[Dir1 Shortcut Group]
Name=dokumenty
Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable --class=myserver -x ranger /home/yemu/dokumenty
TargetEnvironment=Unity
[Dir2 Shortcut Group]
Name=wideo@optiplex
Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable --class=myserver -x ranger /media/optiplex/wideo
```

The crucial thing is to add wmclass and then set terminal as false.